# Locking cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want my macro to only lock 3 cells[not allow user to edit] in row 2, and for that I have written below function.

```
Private Sub MasterHeaderLock(wksMaster As Worksheet)
    wksMaster.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    wksMaster.Range(wksMaster.Cells(2, 7), wksMaster.Cells(2, 9)).Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

But this procedure locks the entire sheet. Please let me know what needs to be modified.

Comment: The sheet is locked as default, you need to start with cells.locked=false or something similar

Comment: yeah maybe a wksMaster.Cells.Lockes=false on line 3 will do it

Comment: Both of you are correct. can one of you post your comments as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
 Call MasterHeaderLock(Worksheets("Sheet1"))
End Sub

Private Sub MasterHeaderLock(wksMaster As Worksheet)
    wksMaster.Cells.Locked = False
    wksMaster.Unprotect
    wksMaster.Range(wksMaster.Cells(2, 7), wksMaster.Cells(2, 9)).Locked = True
    wksMaster.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to update your solution in line 6, 8 and 10! Line 6: `wksMaster.Cells.Locked = False`. And in lines 8, 10 it should be `wksMaster` instead of `ActiveSheet`. Finally, you should remove `wksMaster.Activate`. That is unnecessary.